# select and check box not rendering corrrectly after refresh (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Hi I am trying to set the option of a select element and a check box like this:

```
  if($('[name='+results.rows.item(i).id+']').is("Select")){                               
     $('[name='+results.rows.item(i).id+']').get(0).selectedIndex=results.rows.item(i).aValues;                               
 } else if ($('[name=' + results.rows.item(i).id + ']').attr("type") == "checkbox") {                                
     $('[name='  +results.rows.item(i).id+']').get(0).checked=results.rows.item(i).aValues;
```

It works at first but after I refresh a couple of times the value changes to -1 and sometimes a different number then back after another refresh. I am using WebSQL to store the check value and the selectedIndex and I am using the right values even when it is assigned the wrong one. Doing the same thing in Chrome causes no problem, it does create a lot of database instances in Safari but I heard that was a UI problem. Any ideas? Maybe I am assigning the values tot he elements wrong? Or perhaps it has to do with the fact that I am running Safari on windows?

**Update 3**

So I figured it out. I was refreshing to fast before the page can be displayed. But now it is happening in IE. I try to see if it was a rendering problem like in Safaris but it's not. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code or is it a browser bug?

**Update:**

I tried it in Opera and it does the same thing as in Safari. After refreshing a lot in Opera the page will go bank and refreshing brings it back.

**Update 2**

For the check box I was using a string and needed a boolean. So by using a simple if-else I solved that problem. Still Struggling with the select. It still uses -1 sometimes.

Comment: Hi, are you firing this script with $( document ).ready() ?

Comment: @Bungus not exactly. The function is called when I click a button so I don't need it with a $(document).ready(). It works fine in Chrome.